# SelectOneMenu and valueChangeListener error when set disabled attribute

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am working with a `<h:selectOneMenu>` component. It has the `disabled` attribute set. Due to this I am unable to use a `valueChangeListener` on the component. I tried using the `<a4j:actionListener>` tag, but I get an error saying the parent tag is not of type `ActionSource`. Is there any other way of triggering an action when the selected value changes?

Here's the tag:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="auto" name="name" value="auto" onclick="onclickfunction  (this);"> </input>
</td>
<td>
<h:selectOneMenu id="abc" value="#{bean.val}" disabled="true">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select ..." itemValue=""/>    
     <f:selectItems id="list" value="#{bean.list}"/>          
     <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" limitRender="true" 
     listener="#{bean.listener}" render="other" />                        
     </h:selectOneMenu> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="manual" name="name" value="manual"   onclick="onclickfunction  (this);"> </input>
</td>
<td>
<h:selectOneMenu id="xyz" value="#{bean.val}" disabled="true">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select ..." itemValue=""/>    
     <f:selectItems id="list" value="#{bean.list}"/>          
     <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" limitRender="true" 
     listener="#{bean.listener}" render="other" />                        
     </h:selectOneMenu> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The tag starts out with disabled set to to true. The disabled attribute is changed via javascript.I had to do this via javascript due to a design choice I made. This select tag is one of two tags that the user can toggle using a radio button. I couldn't use the JSF radiobutton tag as it requires an f:selectitem child tag. I just need a radio button for toggling between 2 select tags.

Comment: It would be better to provide your actual code in form of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to have a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: If the input is disabled, how exactly are you changing its value then? Via JavaScript?

Comment: @BalusC, yes,I am changing it via javascript. I will add more detail to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the `disabled` attribute evaluate `true` only during [render response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getRenderResponse%28%29).

```
<h:selectOneMenu ... disabled="#{facesContext.renderResponse}" />
```

This way it's enabled in all other phases like apply request values and update model values, allowing JSF to collect the submitted value and invoking the setter with it.

An alternative is to let the radio button use JSF ajax or `<a4j:jsFunction>` to update the dropdowns.

Comment: when the page first loads the EL "#{facesContext.renderResponse}" returns false. But I need the menu to be disabled on page load, and then enabled depending on the radio button selected by the user. To your other option, how would I associate a regular HTML radio button with an <a4j:jsFunction> tag? I tried to look for examples and couldn't find any.

Comment: Interesting, which JSF impl/version? What if you use `#{not facesContext.postback or facesContext.renderResponse}`? As to `<a4j:jsFunction>`, it basically generates a JS function which links to a JSF managed bean action method. You just have to give the JS function a name e.g. `name="foo"` and then use it as `onclick="foo()"`. See also http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=jsFunction&skin=blueSky

Comment: JSF 2.0. I'll try the negative EL

Comment: The first option of using EL did not work for me. The <a4j:jsFunction> did work. I had to add a couple of things to make the whole thing work. I set the checked attribute of the HTML radio button to a bean property(JSF EL) and set it to true/false whenever the jsfunction was called. Without it the radio buttons were being unselected after the jsfunction completed. Thanks BalusC.